# SQL Server DATEDIFF hour rounding

Tags: sql-server, date

Can anyone explain why

```
select DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2018-02-01 08:30:00', '2018-02-01 10:00:00')
```

is returning 2, and

```
select DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2018-02-01 08:00:00', '2018-02-01 9:30:00')
```

is returning 1?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't find my answer on MSDN..

I would expect them to both return 1 (round down to the nearest full hour), an example on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: MSDN does explain what's happening. There is no rounding involved. `DATEDIFF` counts the interval transitions.`Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted, it's because DATEDIFF uses boundaries (for hours, it is 09:00, 10:00, 11:00 etc).

If you want rounded down hours, then simply apply some integer division to a minute difference

```
 select DATEDIFF(minute, '2018-02-01 08:00:00', '2018-02-01 9:30:00') / 60
```

Comment: Makes sense, I was expecting for this to behave like .NET date substraction, I'll make a mental note never to use DATEDIFF with a boundary 'precision' that's less or equal than the precision I expect to be stored in the database

Answer (score 3):

For hours it will ignore the Minutes, seconds etc... see this in seconds

```
select DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2018-02-01 08:30:00', '2018-02-01 10:00:00')
select DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2018-02-01 08:00:00', '2018-02-01 9:30:00')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
-----------
5400

(1 row affected)


-----------
5400

(1 row affected)
```

**Get the difference in seconds and the convert to Hours.**

**Check this out. - Changed code**

```
select DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2018-02-01 08:30:00', '2018-02-01 10:00:00') / 3600.0


---------------------------------------
1.500000

(1 row affected)


select DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2018-02-01 08:00:00', '2018-02-01 9:30:00') / 3600.0



---------------------------------------
1.500000

(1 row affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because only "hour" values (circled in the picture below) are used for the calculation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The minutes and seconds are not used to get the difference on hours:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2018-02-01 08:59:59', '2018-02-01 9:00:00') -- 1 (9-8 = 1)
```

> The difference between the `startdate` and `endate` in each statement crosses one calendar or time boundary of its datepart.
>   source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql#datepart-boundaries